# WPF combo box text color doesn't change

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I need to make the text of the combobox items in a combobox change color to white when the item is selected.  I can currently change the background color under those conditions however setting `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>` inside of the same style trigger that changes the background color doesn't change anything.

**Sample XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF648CBE"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also, if i change the foreground setter to change the font size or boldness, that works.  I am not sure why I can do that but not change the color.

Comment: So that trigger could set Foreground its value has to be set in Setter.

Comment: Style Triggers can't override local values. Post your full XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I did not understand the WPF styling hierarchy.  Elsewhere in the XAML my combobox foreground color was being overridden by a data binding styling block.  Once that was removed, the foreground color was able to be changed.